# docker build starting slow

Tags: docker, performance, dns, docker-build

I'm testing docker builds on two different systems. Ubuntu and Arch linux. I'm experiencing significant slow docker build starting  speeds (same Dockerfile) on Arch linux (better/newer machine).

In both systems
Docker version 20.10.12
Storage Driver: overlay2

Further investigations shows that there is no delay between creation of layers. Initial time to start the build is the culprit

Comment: Is there any dependency mismatch in Arch?

Comment: There could be minor dependency differences, Arch being rolling updated, tend to use newer version than ubuntu. On the side note, I have seen the same slowness in fedora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the additional DNS lookup's causing the start delay.
Removing the extra mirrors from  .docker/config.json  did the trick

```
cat .docker/config.json 
{
  "credHelpers": {
    "asia.gcr.io": "gcloud"
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not just DNS, it's generating credentials to login to each of the listed registries even when you only push/pull from one of them.

Comment: Yes. its GCR tokens, it had several mirrors this was casing the initial slowness